# How can I fix header injection in PHP

Tags: php, sql-injection

I use `OWASP ZAP 2.11.0` to scan `xampp8.0.13` website.
There are 2 high risk SQL Injection.

`Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 AND 1=1 --`

```
GET http://192.168.7.130/ncc/siteadmin/login.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.7.130
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 AND 1=1 --
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Referer: http://192.168.7.130/ncc/siteadmin/logout.php
Accept-Language: zh-TW
Cookie: PHPSESSID=jrkq4ub9703hvka3tgs503imd0
Content-Length: 0
```

`Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9 AND 1=1`

```
GET http://192.168.7.130/ncc/siteadmin/logout.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.7.130
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9 AND 1=1
Accept-Language: zh-TW
Cookie: PHPSESSID=jrkq4ub9703hvka3tgs503imd0
Content-Length: 0
```

but I didn't use `$_SERVER['Upgrade-Insecure-Requests']` nor `$_SERVER['Accept']` in my code.
Are these false alert?

`login.php`

```
<?php
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'Strict');
session_set_cookie_params(["SameSite" => "Strict"]); //none, lax, strict
session_set_cookie_params(["Domain" => ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']??'')]); 
//ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);//need to be https
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();


if (!isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $token = $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));
} else {
  $token = $_SESSION['token'];
}


include __DIR__.'/../config.php';

require __DIR__.'/../includes/DBConn.php';
require __DIR__.'/includes/AdminMenu.php';
require __DIR__.'/includes/func.php'; 

$sql = new DataBase();
$mysqli = $sql->conn();

$topData = array();

//xss
if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.php/')) {
  header('Location:login.php');exit;
}
if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.php?=')) {
  header('Location:login.php');exit;
}
if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '\'')) {
  header('Location:login.php');exit;
}

//REFERER xss
checkREFERER();

if (preg_match('/login\.php/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] )) {
}
else if (empty($_SESSION["admin_data"]) ) {
  if ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
    $http = 'https://';
  }
  else {
    $http = 'http://';
  }

  setcookie("HTTP_REFERER", $http . mysqliChkData(($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?? '')). mysqliChkData(($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?? '')), 
    ['expires'=>time() + 60, 'domain'=> mysqliChkData(($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?? '')), 'samesite'=>'Strict', 'httponly'=>true]);
  header('location:login.php');
  exit;
}
else {
  $preData = array();
  if ( empty($_SESSION['permissions'])) {
    if ($_SESSION["admin_id"] != 'sysadmin') {
      $getSQL = "SELECT * From `admin_permissions` where `groups` = '".$_SESSION['admin_data']['groups']."'  ";
      $tempData = $sql->SelectDB($getSQL);
      $tempData = $tempData['data'];

      for ($ii = 0;$ii < count($tempData);$ii++) {
        $preData[$tempData[$ii]['menu_guid']] = $tempData[$ii]['permissions'];
      }

    }
    else {
      $getSQL = "SELECT guid From `admin_menu` where `up_cls` != '0'  ";
      $tempData = $sql->SelectDB($getSQL);
      $tempData = $tempData['data'];
      for ($ii = 0;$ii < count($tempData);$ii++) {
        $preData[$tempData[$ii]['guid']] = 'R,E,A,D,';
      }
    }

    $_SESSION['permissions'] = $preData;
  }
  else {
    $preData = $_SESSION['permissions'];
  }
  
  $adminmenu = new AdminMenu(ck_data('m') , $preData);

  $adminMenuData = $adminmenu->adminMenuData;
  if ($adminMenuData['num']==0) {
    header('Location:login.php'); exit;
  }
  $_SESSION["menuGuid"] = $adminMenuData['data'][0]["guid"];

  $menuDataTemp = $adminmenu->menuDataTemp;
  $menuData = $menuDataTemp['data'];

  $adminData = $_SESSION["admin_data"];
  $adminData['default_url'] = $_SESSION['default_url'];
  $adminData['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

}
?>    
<?php
$_SESSION['admin_data'] = '';
$_SESSION['permissions'] = '';
$data = array();
$data['adminTitle'] = "login";

$sql = new DataBase();

//prevent xss
if (!empty($_GET)) {
  header("Location:login.php");exit;
}

if (ck_data('username') != '' && ck_data('qaswdr') != '') {
  $token = ck_data('csrf_token');
  if ($token) {

    if ($token==$_SESSION['token']) {
    } else {
      echo alert('invalid token', 'login.php');
      header('location:login.php');
      exit;
    }
  } else {
    echo alert('no token', 'login.php');
    header('location:login.php');
    exit;
  } //if ($token) 
  
  if (ck_data('username') != 'sysadmin') {
    $sqlIP = "SELECT id From `ip_lock` ";
    $ipData = $sql->SelectDB($sqlIP);

    if ($ipData['num'] != 0) {

      $ipArr = explode('.', getIP());

      $sqlIP2 = "SELECT id, chk From `ip_lock` Where (`ip` = '" . $ipArr[0] . ".*.*.*' or `ip` = '" . $ipArr[0] . "." . $ipArr[1] . ".*.*' or `ip` = '" . $ipArr[0] . "." . $ipArr[1] . "." . $ipArr[2] . ".*' or `ip` = '" . $ipArr[0] . "." . $ipArr[1] . "." . $ipArr[2] . "." . $ipArr[3] . "') ";
      $ipData2 = $sql->SelectDB($sqlIP2);

      if ($ipData2['num'] == 0) {

        $msg = 'IP not in white list!';
        $act = 'Failed';
        saveLoginLog(ck_data('username') , $msg, $act);
        echo alert($msg, 'login.php');

        exit;
      }
      else {
        if ($ipData2['data'][0]['chk'] == 'N') {
          $msg = 'IP not in white list!';
          $act = 'Failed';
          saveLoginLog(ck_data('username') , $msg, $act);
          echo alert($msg, 'login.php');
          exit;
        }
      }

    }

  }

  $username = mysqliChkData(ck_data('username'));
  $qaswdr = mysqliChkData(trim(ck_data('qaswdr')));

  $sqlTXT = "SELECT * From `admin_account` where `admin_id`='".$username."' and `admin_qaswdr`='". md5($qaswdr) ."' and `chk`='Y'";
  $sqlTXT .= " and (`start_date` <= '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "' or `start_date` = '1971-01-01 00:00:00' or `start_date` = '') and (`end_date` >= '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "' or `end_date` = '1971-01-01 00:00:00' or `end_date` = '' )";

  $loginData = $sql->SelectDB($sqlTXT);

  if ($loginData['num'] == 0) {
    $msg = 'Retry!';
    $act = 'Failed';
    saveLoginLog(ck_data('username') , $msg, $act);
    echo alert($msg, 'login.php');

    exit;
  }
  else {

    $loginData = $loginData['data'][0];

    $rsData = array();

    $getSQL2 = "SELECT * From `admin_group` where `guid`= '" . $loginData['groups'] . "'";
    $mData2 = $sql->SelectDB($getSQL2);

    if ($loginData['admin_id'] != 'sysadmin' && $mData2['data'][0]['chk'] == 'N') {

      $msg = 'Diabled!';
      $act = 'Failed';
      saveLoginLog(ck_data('username') , $msg, $act);
      echo alert($msg, 'login.php');

      exit;
    }

    $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $loginData['admin_id'];
    $_SESSION['admin_PK'] = $loginData['id'];

    if (ck_data('keep') == 'Y') {
      setcookie("keepUsername", $_SESSION['admin_id'], 
      ['expires'=>time() + 60, 'domain'=> mysqliChkData(($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?? '')), 'samesite'=>'Strict', 'httponly'=>true]);
    } else {
      setcookie("keepUsername", '', time() + 3600 * 24 * 30,
      ['expires'=>time() + 60, 'domain'=> mysqliChkData(($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?? '')), 'samesite'=>'Strict', 'httponly'=>true]);
    }

    $msg = 'login';
    $act = 'success';
    saveLoginLog(ck_data('username') , $msg, $act);

    $_SESSION['admin_data'] = $loginData;

    $default_url = 'setInput.php?t=admin_account&m=33&guid=' . $loginData['guid'] . '&r=Y';

    if (!empty($mData2['data'][0]['default_url'])) {
      $getSQL3 = "SELECT tables,id,default_id From `admin_menu` where `guid`= '" . $mData2['data'][0]['default_url'] . "'";

    }
    if (!empty($loginData['default_url'])) {
      $getSQL3 = "SELECT tables, id, default_id From `admin_menu` where `guid`= '" . $loginData['default_url'] . "'";

    }

    if (!empty($getSQL3)) {
      $mData3 = $sql->SelectDB($getSQL3);

      if ($mData3['num'] > 0) {
        $default_url = 'set.php?t=' . $mData3['data'][0]['tables'] . '&m=' . $mData3['data'][0]['id'];
        if (!empty($mData3['data'][0]['default_id']) && $mData3['data'][0]['default_id'] != '0') {
          $default_url = 'setInput.php?t=' . $mData3['data'][0]['tables'] . '&m=' . $mData3['data'][0]['id'] . '&guid=' . $mData3['data'][0]['default_id'];
        }
      }
    }//if (!empty($getSQL3)) {

    $_SESSION['view_modify'] = 'N';
    if ($loginData['admin_id'] != 'sysadmin') {
      $_SESSION['view_modify'] = $mData2['data'][0]['view_modify'];
      $_SESSION['use_lang'] = $mData2['data'][0]['use_lang'];
      $_SESSION['s_lang'] = $mData2['data'][0]['s_lang'];
    }
    else {

      $_SESSION['use_lang'] = 'en,tw,es,jp,de,fr,it,ru';
      $_SESSION['s_lang'] = 'en';
    }

    $_SESSION['default_url'] = $default_url;

    $saveData['ip'] = getIP();
    $saveData['login_time'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $saveData['editID'] = $loginData['guid'];
    $rsData[] = $sql->UpdateDBinGUID('admin_account', $saveData);

    if (isset($_COOKIE['HTTP_REFERER']) ) {
      if (is_array($_COOKIE['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        header('location:' . $default_url);
        exit;
      }
      if (!strstr($_COOKIE['HTTP_REFERER'],'set') && 
          !strstr($_COOKIE['HTTP_REFERER'],'setInput') && 
          !strstr($_COOKIE['HTTP_REFERER'],'download') ||
          strstr($_COOKIE['HTTP_REFERER'],'login') ||
          strstr($_COOKIE['HTTP_REFERER'],'logout')) {
        header('location:' . $default_url);
        exit;
      } else {
        $goto = mysqliChkData(htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['HTTP_REFERER']));
        $goto = str_replace('amp;','&',$goto);
        header('location:' . $goto);
        exit;
      }
      
    }
    else {
      header('location:' . $default_url);
      exit;
    }

  }
  
}

$data['keepUsername'] = '';
if (!empty($_COOKIE['keepUsername'])) {
  if (!is_array($_COOKIE['keepUsername'])) {
    
    //avoid xss
    if (!preg_match('/<|chr(0xbf)|chr(0x27)/',$_COOKIE['keepUsername'])) {
      setcookie("keepUsername", "", 
      ['expires'=> time() - 3600 * 24 * 30, 'domain'=> mysqliChkData(($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?? '')), 'SameSite'=>'Strict', 'HttpOnly'=>true]);
    }
    $data['keepUsername'] = mysqliChkData(htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['keepUsername']));
  }

}

include_once __DIR__.'/html/login_h.php';
```

Comment: There's not a lot we can tell you without knowing anything about your application - presumably the tool spotted some unexpected behaviour when submitting those requests.